# In C, what does a variable declaration with two asterisks (**) mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I am working with C and I'm a bit rusty.  I am aware that `*` has three uses:

1. Declaring a pointer.
2. Dereferencing a pointer.
3. Multiplication

However, what does it mean when there are two asterisks (`**`) before a variable declaration:

```
char **aPointer = ...
```

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It declares a **pointer to a `char` pointer**.

The usage of such a pointer would be to do such things like:

```
void setCharPointerToX(char ** character) {
   *character = "x"; //using the dereference operator (*) to get the value that character points to (in this case a char pointer
}
char *y;
setCharPointerToX(&y); //using the address-of (&) operator here
printf("%s", y); //x
```

Here's another example:

```
char *original = "awesomeness";
char **pointer_to_original = &original;
(*pointer_to_original) = "is awesome";
printf("%s", original); //is awesome
```

Use of `**` with arrays:

```
char** array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * 2); //2 elements

(*array) = "Hey"; //equivalent to array[0]
*(array + 1) = "There";  //array[1]

printf("%s", array[1]); //outputs There
```

The `[]` operator on arrays does essentially pointer arithmetic on the front pointer, so, the way `array[1]` would be evaluated is as follows:

```
array[1] == *(array + 1);
```

This is one of the reasons why array indices start from `0`, because:

```
array[0] == *(array + 0) == *(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  What is the use case for having a pointer to a pointer ?

Comment: @Jacob - Is the : valid C syntax ?  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: A `char **` can also represent a list of strings, e.g. `argv` or the list of arguments you pass to `execvp` or similar.

Comment: @Matt This is true. I should add an example of that in there.

Comment: *(array) = (*array) = *array ??

Answer (score 49):

C and C++ allows the use of pointers that point to pointers (say that five times fast). Take a look at the following code:

```
char a;
char *b;
char **c;

a = 'Z';
b = &a; // read as "address of a"
c = &b; // read as "address of b"
```

The variable `a` holds a character. The variable `b` points to a location in memory that contains a character. The variable `c` points to a location in memory that contains a pointer that points to a location in memory that contains a character.

Suppose that the variable `a` stores its data at address 1000 (BEWARE: example memory locations are totally made up). Suppose that the variable `b` stores its data at address 2000, and that the variable `c` stores its data at address 3000. Given all of this, we have the following memory layout:

```
MEMORY LOCATION 1000 (variable a): 'Z'
MEMORY LOCATION 2000 (variable b): 1000 <--- points to memory location 1000
MEMORY LOCATION 3000 (variable c): 2000 <--- points to memory location 2000
```

Answer (score 9):

It declares `aPointer` as a pointer to a pointer to char.

Declarations in C are centered around the types of *expressions*; the common name for it is "declaration mimics use".  As a simple example, suppose we have a pointer to int named `p` and we want to access the integer value it's currently pointing to.  We would *dereference* the pointer with the unary `*` operator, like so:

```
x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, so the declaration of the pointer variable `p` is

```
int *p;
```

In this case, `aPointer` is a pointer to a pointer to char; if we want to get to the character value it's currently pointing to, we would have to dereference it twice:

```
c = **aPointer;
```

So, going by the logic above, the declaration of the pointer variable `aPointer` is

```
char **aPointer;
```

because the type of the *expression* `**aPointer` is `char`.

Why would you ever have a pointer to a pointer?  It shows up in several contexts:

- You want a function to modify a pointer value; one example is the `strtol` library function, whose prototype (as of C99) is

  ```
  long strtol(const char * restrict str, char ** restrict ptr, int base);
  ```

  The second argument is a pointer to a pointer to char; when you call `strtol`, you pass the address of a pointer to char as the second argument, and after the call it will point to the first character in the string that wasn't converted.

  Remember that in most contexts, an expression of type "N-element array of T" is implicitly converted to type "pointer to T", and its value is the address of the first element of the array.  If "T" is "pointer to char", then an expression of type "N-element array of pointer to char" will be converted to "pointer to pointer to char".  For example:

  ```
      void foo(char **arr)
      {
        size_t i = 0;
        for (i = 0; arr[i] != NULL; i++)
          printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
      }

      void bar(void)
      {
        char *ptrs[N] = {"foo", "bar", "bletch", NULL};
        foo(ptrs); // ptrs decays from char *[N] to char **
      }
  ```

  You want to dynamically allocate a multi-dimensional array:

  ```
  #define ROWS ...
  #define COLS ...
  ...
  char **arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * ROWS);
  if (arr)
  {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = malloc(sizeof *arr[i] * COLS);
      if (arr[i])
      {
        size_t j;
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
          arr[i][j] = ...;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

It means that `aPointer` points to a char pointer.

So

```
aPointer: pointer to char pointer

*aPointer :pointer to char

**aPointer: char
```

An example of its usage is creating a dynamic array of c strings

`char **aPointer = (char**) malloc(num_strings);`

*aPointer gives you a char*, which can be used to represent a zero-terminated string.

```
*aPointer = (char*)malloc( string_len + 1); //aPointer[0]
*(aPointer + 1) = (char*)malloc( string_len + 1); //aPointer[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointer to a pointer to `char`.