# Pointer to Pointer in C function; Linked Lists

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

Before this is marked as a dup, I have read 
[In C, what does a variable declaration with two asterisks (**) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318881/in-c-what-does-a-variable-declaration-with-two-asterisks-mean)
[I don't understand the implementation of inserting a new node in linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168364/i-dont-understand-the-implementation-of-inserting-a-new-node-in-linked-list) 
And I still am struggling with the logical steps of the double asterisk. I understand that in a linked list I need to create a new node, dynamically allocate space for it and then relabel the new node as the head. 
I just don't understand the logical steps of the function between the `&head` and the double asterisk. What is pointing to what and how does the implementation of the double asterisk work here?

```
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

push(&head, 2);
```

Comment: Use pen and paper. Execute the code by hand. Draw pictures. Write the value of variables.

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard `push` function - it's more like a `createAndPush`

Comment: 1. Takes in the address as a pointer to a pointer (Because it's a node)   
2. Creates 2nd node 

3. Makes the new node point to the (old) head 


4. Then relabels the new_node as head (Or whatever the 1st item is in list)

 
So the double asterisk is just a double asterisk because of the nature of the struct of the node? Like struct node ** is basically declaring the type of node and datatype?

Comment: Function calls work like assignments: The arguments are assigned to the parameters. We have `head_ref = &head`, so `head_ref` is pointing to `head`.

Comment: @klutt Yeah actually pen and paper worked out for me. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the caller passes `&head` as the first argument,

- `head_ref` is equal to `&head`
- `*head_ref` is equal to `head`.

The call `push(&head, 2)` therefore has the same net effect as writing code in the caller as follows.

```
/*   struct node **head_ref = &head;   */

struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new_node->data = 2;
new_node->next = head;       /*   new_node = (*head_ref) */
head = new_node;             /*    (*head_ref) = new_node */
```

I've commented out all usage of `head_ref` since that is a variable local to the function, and not seen by the caller.    The comments in the last two statements show the equivalence.

Note that I've also removed the type conversion of the result from `malloc()`, as such a thing is generally considered poor practice in C.

Comment: Thanks I actually realize now that it has to be double asterisk in order to get at the address and have it take in an address. I thought that there were some logical steps that I was missing in that it was pointing to something unknown in preparation for the new node (Which was not created yet!) Now I see thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, in order to understand what is going on you have to understand what pointer to pointer is as well as meaning of deference operator `*`.
Then you can follow the code:

`void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)`

Function `push` has two arguments: a pointer to a pointer and `int` value.

`head` is a pointer to a variable of type `struct node`

`struct node* head;`

To properly call `push` you have to take the address of the `head` pointer.
It is done by use of `&` operator. Then `&head` is the address of the pointer.

`struct node **head_ref = &head;`